# Assignment of dereferenced object to an object causes seg fault

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following simple program as an illustration:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    string *my_str;

    name = "foo";
    my_str = (string *) malloc(sizeof(*my_str));

    *my_str = name;                           // fault line
    // my_str = new(my_str) string(name);     // fix
}
```

Code compiles, but during executing I get an seg fault:

```
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

$ gdb -q ./a.out ./core.31114
.....
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  __exchange_and_add_single (__mem=<optimized out>, __val=-1)
    at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:66
66      /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __exchange_and_add_single (__mem=<optimized out>, __val=-1)
    at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:66
#1  __exchange_and_add_dispatch (__mem=0xfffffffffffffff8, __val=<optimized out>)
    at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:83
#2  std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose (this=0xffffffffffffffe8, __a=...)
    at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:242
#3  0x00007fbab7a5ff06 in _M_grab (__alloc1=..., this=<optimized out>, __alloc2=...)
    at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:226
#4  _M_grab (__alloc2=..., __alloc1=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:244
#5  std::string::assign (this=0x99a040, __str=...) at /home/packages/gcc/4.7/w/gcc-4.7-4.7.2/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:251
#6  0x00000000004008b3 in main () at ./strassign.cc:12
```

I know the fix to the problem (line commented with string "fix")  and I also know I should be using new in the first place.  THIS IS A MADE UP EXAMPLE.  I ran into this issue while debugging a large piece of code and I have no interest (at the moment) of going through and replacing all the mallocs with new.

I am just trying to understand underneath the hood (basically explanation of the bt) why the assignment seg faults.  I was thinking that the string copy assignment operator of object *my_str would be called and everything should work out.  But based on the outcome, I guess not.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: You've allocated memory for a string, but you haven't actually constructed one. Use `new string` instead.

Comment: or inplace-construct it in that memory with `new((void*)my_str) string;`.

Comment: If you're using malloc in C++, chances are you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @dlf I purposely used malloc in my code to illustrated the issue.  It is a made up example.

Comment: @Borgleader This is a made up example, but thank you.

Comment: @AhmedA It's not an issue at all. You have triggered undefined behavior by using an object without constructing it first. What's likely happening is that when you attempt to copy the object, the `std::string` assignment operator is trying to use an uninitialized pointer, and is blowing up as a result.

Comment: @AhmedA Ok. In that case, see Deduplicator's suggestion for performing inplace construction (after doing the malloc).

Comment: @cdhowie that was my thinking.  By looking at the stack track, can you or one tell if the "copy assignment operator" is indeed being called?

Comment: Regarding the edits, yes, the assignment operator is being called by your code, and as cdhowie mentioned, the reason it blows up is almost certainly because the assignment operator tries to free the old string as a first step, but the data members that hold the length and location of the old string contain random values since the memory was never initialized (it also could decide to reuse the old buffer if its big enough, but that's bad too).

Comment: @AhmedA - The string *object* `my_str` is bogus, regardless of your call to `malloc`.  Any attempt to use it wrt assignment, copying, yields undefined behavior.  So I don't know what looking at stack traces is going to buy you.  Just don't construct non-PODs using malloc(), unless you are using placement-new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my_str = (string *) malloc(sizeof(*my_str));
```

This allocates space for a `string` on the heap (not on the C++ free-store).

What it *does not* do is initialize the memory.
Thus, while we now have space enough for a `string`, we *do not* have a `string`.

Your fix

```
my_str = new(my_str) string(name);
// Should cast the pointer-argument to `void*` before giving it to `new`.
// Otherwise, some other custom overload of `operator new` might match better.
```

uses a placement-new-expression to call the constructor, and establish the object-invariants (thus beginning the `string`-objects lifetime).

BTW: `constexpr void* operator new(size_t, void*)` is defined to just return its second argument, so only the second part of the new-expression, the ctor-call, has any effect.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you mind sharing what is happening in the statement *my_str = name.    Is the "copy assignment operator" being called?

Comment: Yes, the copy-assignment operator.

Comment: Is frame 5 in the bt the hint (give a away) that the string copy assignment operator is being called?

Comment: While that hints such might be, it does not actually say so. The call to the copy-assignment-operator was obviously inlined (it was just a delegate to `assign` anyway). I looked at your code, operator is `=`, the rhs was not an xvalue, both were strings, ergo copy-assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The **new** expression (like `std::string* myString = new myString("hello"));`) performs two steps. First it allocates the memory for the object, then it calls the constructor to initialize the object.  When you use malloc to allocate your memory, you have the memory for the object itself but it is not initialized in any way...just whatever arbitrary memory happened to be there.

In the case of `std::string` the actual string data is allocated separately.  When you assign to the object, it will try to copy the data to whatever location happens to be in the data pointer inside the object, which is probably not yours.

By calling the placement new, you are calling the constructor to initialize the object whose memory you have allocated separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want my_str to point to the same data as name, then what you want is

```
my_str = &name;
```

And the malloc is unneeded. If you want to make a copy of it, then use strcpy (in C) or the line you have shown as a fix for C++.

Right now you're trying to set the data that my_str points to as a string object (assigning a pointer to a dereferenced value).